# How do I get latest row with 'join' or 'leave' value, and sort them?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table that tracks join and leave events from players on a game and each of it's servers. The problem I have is, how do I know whose offline and who's online?

This is how my table is structured, and some sample values:

```
CREATE TABLE `b_rbx_connections` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `place` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('join','leave') NOT NULL,
  `followed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0/null=none',
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `b_rbx_connections` (`id`, `server`, `place`, `player`, `type`, `followed`, `time`) VALUES
(1, '83889ac4-eaf9-45af-8b9d-fa1b14dba952', 1253620452, 50180001, 'join', NULL, '2018-02-10 06:04:30'),
(2, '83889ac4-eaf9-45af-8b9d-fa1b14dba952', 1253620452, 50180001, 'leave', NULL, '2018-02-10 06:32:27'),
(3, '9f1aabe0-e314-46f1-bb81-c45ea70fdae9', 1253620452, 50180001, 'join', NULL, '2018-02-11 22:54:53');
```

Each time a player joins a row is inserted with the server id, place id, whether it was a join or leave, and the time of the event.

This is what I've tried so far, but it only works if each player has only joined/left once:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT player FROM `b_rbx_connections` WHERE place='$placeId' AND type='join' AND time <= '$timestamp' ORDER BY `time` DESC";
$j = $db->query($q);
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT player FROM `b_rbx_connections` WHERE place='$placeId' AND type='leave' AND time <= '$timestamp' ORDER BY `time` DESC";
$l = $db->query($q);

$this->players = $j->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$this->offline_players = $l->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$this->online_players = array_diff($this->players, $this->offline_players);
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "players": [
        "50180001"
    ],
    "offline_players": [
        "50180001"
    ],
    "online_players": [

    ]
}
```

But it should be.

```
{
    "players": [
        "50180001"
    ],
    "offline_players": [

    ],
    "online_players": [
        "50180001"

    ]
}
```

Note: A place is a game id, a server is the instance id of a server in that game, and a player is the id of that player.

Comment: you can this with one query and use PHP the parse through the data. DISTINCT returns the first instance of a row, so if you order by ID desc, then you are getting the latest state of that record. Then use a loop to search through the result set and seperate into different arrays depending on type.

Comment: you didn't show your expected output, should the `player` have all the online and offline players.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam sorry, players should show all players, and the 50180001 in offline should be in online

Comment: @Juakali92 how would that query look?

Comment: added an answer for you see if that helps you out, you can get all player online or offline under the `players` and the offline players under `offline` and online players under `online`.

Comment: Do you have a `players` table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes, `b_rbx_players` with id (INT) and player (INT) columns

Comment: 83889ac4-eaf9-45af-8b9d-fa1b14dba952 isn't a useful thing to put in a sample data set. 'a' would work just as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group the player within a search to get the "latest" status of each player.  Then use that new array to parse out the results you want.

```
SELECT  *
FROM (Select * FROM `b_rbx_connections` order by time desc) as results
GROUP BY player
```

Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd03cb/3/0, where I added more players to test the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.player, (
    select c.type
    from b_rbx_connections c
    where c.player = p.player
      and c.place = 1253620452
    order by c.time desc
    limit 1
) as type
from b_rbx_players p
```

This will return all players and the `type` of the last row in the connections table for a given `place`. If the player has no entry, the `type` will be NULL (which can be considered offline).

Now use a PHP loop to assign the players to the different arrays.

Comment: It works [here](http://rextester.com/FSQ37007) with your "sample data". Please post sample data where it doesn't work.